# How to hide/show <md-progress-bar> on VueJS Material

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-material

I'm trying use `<md-progress-bar>` component from [here](https://vuematerial.io/components/progress-bar). The problem is that I can`t determinate to hide and show using variable value. I'm trying do it, but not works.

```
<template>
...
 <md-progress-bar md-mode="indeterminate" :md-active.sync="showProgressBar"></md-progress-bar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
...
data() {
 return {
  ...,
  showProgressBar: false
  }
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does `md-active`? this prop does not exists in component props.

Comment: I use it on md-dialog. Not sure to use on progress

Comment: `v-show="showProgressBar"` will show or hide this, may you need this.

Comment: yes, it works...

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work

```
<md-progress-bar md-mode="indeterminate" v-show="showProgressBar"></md-progress-bar>
```